# Processing3 weird characters and font

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, processing

I just downloaded the 64-bit Windows version of Processing 3.2.3 from [here](https://processing.org/download/?processing) and I am getting weird characters in my application. Happens only in some parts of the application.

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

This problem is fixed in recent versions of Processing and the issue is closed. If you are experiencing this problem and using Processing between 3.1 and 3.3, upgrade to 3.3 or later.

**Old answer**:

This problem is currently documented with an open ticket on the [Processing Issues](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/) GitHub site:

- [Broken characters in the Welcome Page and the Contribution Manager #4747](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4747)

The issue is still open, but some users report that an effective workaround is **deleting the system font Source Sans Pro** -- it may be conflicting with Processing's bundled font.

The issue was fixed in Processing 3.3 on by [renaming the font](https://github.com/processing/processing/commit/93749da60c3a515d5e945f710947c1fdffa681f1). Upgrade to 3.3+ to get the fix.